# Linear Layout and children not visible

Tags: android-layout

Hi sorry I am having difficulty in getting my layout to been seen when I run the application
I don't see anything when I run my application

[image: Here is the design I'm going for[][1]]

here is my XML code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Name" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrlText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:layout_height="638dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lltext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hllsend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtInput"
                android:layout_width="159dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How do I make my items visible when running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your simple layout code, there are many problems. For example:

1.

```
android:layout_width="409dp"
android:layout_height="729dp"
```

such android screen size is hard to get. And in Android layout principal, you'd better use relative layout rather than such hard code size. Here you can replace it with match_parent or wrap_content.

2. In the same way.

   ```
   android:layout_height="638dp"
   ```

totally over screen height ,make no space for hllsend to show.

I suggest you learn some android layout principal before write android app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to add `LinearLayout` in `ConstraintLayout` and I think it's the issue with your code you just need to make you `LinearLayout` as a parent and remove your `ConstraintLayout`.

NOTE: please do necessary adjustment.

Please check quick example for your code I didn't run this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="729dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrlText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_height="638dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hllsend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtInput"
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put all your `xml codes` in `LinearLayout` and remove `ConstraintLayout` . thats may helps.